How do I force a Unicode symbol to display as text instead of an emoji?
Unicode symbols such as U+1F512 (lock) look very different in different versions of Windows and don't match the color of the text at all. So I want the lock symbol to be text instead of an emoji, and I want it to appear in the Text of Label for the Tahoma font and font color Gray.
I tried using the variation selector U+FE0E to force emoji to be rendered as text, like this:
Label->Text = L"\U0001F512\uFE0E";
// Label->Text = L"\xD83D\xDD12\xFE0E";
// Label->Text = L"\uD83D\uDD12\uFE0E";

But the lock symbol is still rendered as a weird emoji in Windows 10 (and, I suspect, Windows 11 as well). What am I missing here? Is that even possible?


"I want it to appear in the Text of Label for the Tahoma font" - Tahoma doesn't support U+1F512. Windows is able to use a fallback font when it can't render a character in a selected font.

@RemyLebeau Windows 8.1 displays the lock symbol as expected by default with these lines for Tahoma in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink: MSGOTHIC.TTC,MS UI Gothic MINGLIU.TTC,PMingLiU SIMSUN.TTC,SimSun GULIM.TTC,Gulim. Windows 10 has more lines there and fails to display the expected result by default: MSGOTHIC.TTC,MS UI Gothic MINGLIU.TTC,PMingLiU SIMSUN.TTC,SimSun GULIM.TTC,Gulim YUGOTHM.TTC,Yu Gothic UI MSJH.TTC,Microsoft JhengHei UI MSYH.TTC,Microsoft YaHei UI MALGUN.TTF,Malgun Gothic SEGUISYM.TTF,Segoe UI Symbol

@RemyLebeau I've tried various combinations with both fallback fonts (which support U+1F512 and are installed in the system) and the variation selector, and still nothing works on Windows 10, while Windows 8.1 displays the lock symbol as text by default, even without the variation selector, as expected. I reported a bug RSS-1875 in Embarcadero's Quality Portal.

This question sheds some light on what could be happening here: apparently when using D2D Windows ignores the SystemLink fallback entries and uses another internal one, potentially falling back to Segoe UI Emoji for emoji character ranges (and ignoring the variant selector).
